# Dynamically added objects: quiz questions and answers as radios, but can't read property 'checked' of null

Tags: javascript

I want to make a quiz but don't want to just copy-paste from the simplest code to find on internet, so decided to use objects. So, I have an array of questions. Each question is an object, has a name and an array of answers. Each answer is an object, has id, text and correctiveness. Normally, you can have more than one correct answer for one question.

I know that this problem appears very often, but in many cases (what I read about almost all day today :-) was the wrong position of script or function, but not in my case I am sure, because I try to access the radiobuttons that are created and shown on the page before on-click "Submit".
var showAnswers;

```
function showQuestions(quizQuestions, quizContainer){

 var showAnswers;

 for(var i=0; i<quizQuestions.length; i++){

       quizContainer.innerHTML +=
        '<div class="question">' + quizQuestions[i].question + '</div>';
  {
    for(var j=0; j<quizQuestions[i].answers.length; j++){
   let currId = quizQuestions[i].answers[j].id;

        quizContainer.innerHTML +=
         '<div class="answers">' + 
            '<label>'
             + '<input id=currId type="radio" name="question'+i+'" 
 value=j>'
                + quizQuestions[i].answers[j].answer
            + '</label>'+"<br>"+ '</div>';

      }

    }

   }
```

function showResults(questions, quizContainer, resultsContainer){

```
var userAnswer = '';
var numCorrect = 0;


for(var i=1; i<=questions.length; i++){
 for(var j=1; j<=questions[i].answers.length; j++){
    let currentId = "a"+i+"_"+j;

   if (document.getElementById(currentId).checked){
       userAnswer = j-1;}

    }

    if(questions[i-1].answers[userAnswer].correct = true){

        numCorrect++;


    }

    }



 resultsContainer.innerHTML = numCorrect + ' out of ' + questions.length;
}
showQuestions(myQuizQuestions, quizContainer);



 submitButton.onclick = function(){
    showResults(myQuizQuestions, quizContainer, resultsContainer);
}
```

I make all objects dynamically and show them in HTML page,  which works ok. But after checking radiobuttons ans pressing submit I suppose to be able to check the property "checked" with the help of document.getElementById('the_id_of_current_answer_of current_question'), but I get error "Cannot read property 'checked' of null". I just don't get it. The radiobuttons are created and even displayed correctly, so what's wrong am I doing?

Comment: This is probably an off by one error. Notice how you start at 0 for i in generating, but you start at 1 in checking

Comment: thanks, but even without the checking, console.log(document.getElementById("a1_1")); shows null right after creating those elements

Comment: Hmm does the id appear in the rendered html